# Using .removeAttr('checked') does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I use of codeigniter.see you:[example of my code](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/insert) please fill textbox and checked checkbox next clicked on link add, see yourself that not work `.removeAttr('checked')`

```
newDiv.find('input').each(function () { $(this).removeAttr('checked').val(''); });
```

full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('a.add').live('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $class = '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');
            var newDiv = $(this).closest($class).clone();
            $(this).closest($class).find('.adda').remove()
            //$(this).find('.adda').remove()
            //newDiv.append('<a href="" class="remove_input"></a>')
            newDiv.find('input').each(function () {
                $(this).removeAttr('checked').val('');
            });
            $($class + ':last').after(newDiv);
            //newDiv.remove('.adda')
            //alert(newDiv)
        });

        $('a.remove_input').live('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('div').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

With respect

Comment: What is your question ? What does not work ? Please be more precise.

Comment: @ kbok - This amount is not enough to explain?you read all my posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function, by doing this:

```
$(this).prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newDiv.find('input').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false).val(''); });
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it's a mistake to set the value after removing the attr.

I've had better luck doing this:

```
$(this).attr('checked', false);
```

A checkbox's `checked` state is inseparable from the element; you can no more remove its is-checked/is-not-checked state than you can remove it's HTML-element-ness. Instead, indicate that the checkbox should be unchecked.

Comment: There is no jQuery `.setAttr()` function. Did you mean `.attr()`?

Comment: @Matt Ball I was uncritically repeating the syntax Sheikhasa had inside his .each(). Looks like I wasn't really paying attention. Sample code updated.